# conda environment from windows to linux

Tags: python, ubuntu, conda

I have developed a project on windows using pycharm and I want to deploy in on an ubuntu server.

I am trying to create a `requirements.txt` using these commands:

```
conda list -e > requirements.txt
conda list > requirements.txt
```

Depending on the options the `requirements.txt` looks like any of these:

```
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: win-64
@EXPLICIT
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/blas-1.0-mkl.tar.bz2
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/ca-certificates-2018.03.07-0.tar.bz2
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/icc_rt-2017.0.4-h97af966_0.tar.bz2
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/intel-openmp-2018.0.3-0.tar.bz2
```

Or this

```
# packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\myenvs:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
anyjson                   0.3.3            py36h1110a06_1  
arrow                     0.12.1                   py36_1  
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py36_0  
babel                     2.6.0                    py36_0
```

Or this

```
name: myenv
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - anyjson=0.3.3=py36h1110a06_1
  - arrow=0.12.1=py36_1
  - asn1crypto=0.24.0=py36_0
  - babel=2.6.0=py36_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
```

No matter how I try to do this I get errors on the ubuntu machine, in some cases because the package is for windows: (**/win-64/**)

```
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/ca-certificates-2018.03.07-0.tar.bz2
```

I have read a lot of documentation but I seem not to be able to get what I want. 
[Conda (Python) Virtual Environment is not Portable from Windows to Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39105596/conda-python-virtual-environment-is-not-portable-from-windows-to-linux)

Any solution?

Comment: It could work using `conda env export` output and removing packages only available to `win-64`. Some may require replacement by a linux equivalent.
I think using an install of conda under WSL could solve some of your problems: doing so you can develop under windows with `linux-64` packages directly. Note that I was not able to fully test this configuration (yet).

Comment: Just maybe: If you do not need to pin all dependency versions, something like `pipreqs` or similar tools might only export the top dependencies that are generelly more plattform invariant, and plattform specific ones will be requested on demand. BUT this has many chances to fail, as some packages are not directly used in the source code and have to be manually installed.

Answer (score 15):

By default, conda will export your environment with builds, but builds can be platform-specific.

A solution that worked for me is to use the `--no-build` flag:

```
$ conda env export --no-build > environment.yml
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work... still some windows specific packages are left behind.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing and getting the same issues - got a dozen packages that are windows-specific..

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around why this works for me and also why this isn't the default behavior of `export`.  I mean who wants to export an env that by default is tightly coupled to the machine it was developed on?

Answer (score 5):

I was handling with the same problem, I found this on Anaconda documentation:

> *Conda does not check architecture or dependencies when installing from
> a spec file. To ensure that the packages work correctly, make sure
> that the file was created from a working environment, and use it on
> the same architecture, operating system, and platform, such as
> linux-64 or osx-64*

[Managing enviroments](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

Comment: AKA - conda is basically worthless in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

### Alternative

As an alternative, you export only the depenencies you added and not any transitive deps using `conda env export --from-history` which results in something like

```
name: email_scraper
channels:
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.9
  - img2pdf
  - python-dotenv
  - google-cloud-storage
  - psycopg2
  - pypdf2
  - pytest
  - google-cloud-logging
```

Although this loses versions so you may need to manually add them by cross-referencing the other environmnet.yaml file (tedious).

Platform-related issues often occur in the underlying transitive dependencies.  You are basically making a tradeoff between specificity and tranferability of env.  The default `export` is a highly specific environment that runs on a single OS platform.  The latter is more generic but may internally be different on different OS.

If you are here in 2022, you may want to have a look at [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) as the package manager instead.