# Docker miniconda3 setup error when docker-compose build

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, yaml, miniconda

I am trying to create a docker container for miniconda3 using "docker-compose build", however below error code shows.

**UNANSWERED NEW QUESTION**
Or is there any better way to work with continuumio/miniconda3 docker image to make sure it is pre-installed with some desired list of python packages (for example, through pip install --r requirements.txt or conda create --name myenv --file environment.yml or any other efficient ways)? (or any ways to could continue installing python packages and save those packages after miniconda3 image had been created?)

```
=> ERROR [4/4] RUN conda env create --name data_science --file environment.yml                                                   160.6s 
------
 > [4/4] RUN conda env create --name data_science --file environment.yml:
#8 8.635 Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
#8 148.5 Solving environment: ...working... failed
#8 148.5
#8 148.5 ResolvePackageNotFound:
#8 148.5   - vs2015_runtime==14.29.30037=h902a5da_5
#8 148.5   - python==3.9.7=h7840368_2_cpython
#8 148.5   - setuptools==58.0.4=py39hcbf5309_2
#8 148.5   - sqlite==3.36.0=h8ffe710_2
#8 148.5   - vc==14.2=hb210afc_5
#8 148.5   - openssl==1.1.1l=h8ffe710_0
#8 148.5   - ca-certificates==2021.5.30=h5b45459_0
#8 148.5   - ucrt==10.0.20348.0=h57928b3_0
#8 148.5
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c conda env create --name data_science --file environment.yml]: exit code: 1
ERROR: Service 'node' failed to build : Build failed
```

Below are the details for my Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, environment.yml.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
WORKDIR /data
COPY environment.yml environment.yml
RUN conda env create --name data_science --file environment.yml
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  node:
    build: .  
    volumes: 
      - .:/data
    ports: 
      - 8888:8888
    image: node:data
    container_name: miniconda3
    command:
      - jupyter notebook --port=8888 --ip=0.0.0.0 --allow-root
```

**environment.yml**

```
name: python_data_science
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - default
dependencies:
  - ca-certificates=2021.5.30=h5b45459_0
  - openssl=1.1.1l=h8ffe710_0
  - pip=21.2.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python=3.9.7=h7840368_2_cpython
  - python_abi=3.9=2_cp39
  - setuptools=58.0.4=py39hcbf5309_2
  - sqlite=3.36.0=h8ffe710_2
  - tzdata=2021a=he74cb21_1
  - ucrt=10.0.20348.0=h57928b3_0
  - vc=14.2=hb210afc_5
  - vs2015_runtime=14.29.30037=h902a5da_5
  - wheel=0.37.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
prefix: C:\Users\tys\.conda\envs\python_data_science
```

Hope for help. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED**
**Possible reason of failing**:
I think it is because when i run "conda export env > environment.yml" on windows 10, conda will export my environment with builds, but builds can be platform-specific which is not suitable to be installed in miniconda3 linux in the docker container. For more info, refer to this stackoverflow forum, [conda environment from windows to linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51708668/conda-environment-from-windows-to-linux)

**Possible solution**
(i) (Not sure how to solve yet, but may be could refer to this [blog post](https://uwekorn.com/2021/03/01/deploying-conda-environments-in-docker-how-to-do-it-right.html) for more information. Credit to @merv)
(ii) [repo2docker](https://towardsdatascience.com/docker-without-the-hassle-b98447caedd8)

Comment: Are you going to show us the full output?

Comment: @Klaus D. I have updated and add more error code on this page. And also, since the output is too long, thus I put it into this google docs: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cgLK2zb6MXGdoT2k5K4zR__HhuK3BYtxDIVmFmboQ3c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That env file looks like it came from a Windows machine, but the Miniconda image is Linux. Most of the packages listed are completely unnecessary to include. You might benefit from reading [this blog post](https://uwekorn.com/2021/03/01/deploying-conda-environments-in-docker-how-to-do-it-right.html).

Comment: @merv Thanks for that. Ya, I am running them on vscode windows 10. The blog post seems like would be helpful but a bit complicated for me. I will try to figure it out later. Thanks so much, merv.

Comment: I was playing with your `environment.yml` a little and that is possibly causing the problem. When you change for example your `pip=21.2.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0` to `pip=21.2.4` it stops throwing an error and got installed successfully.

Comment: @Leemosh Thanks for help. But I think same error still appears as mentioned above.

Comment: There is no ambiguity about the problem: it fails because the YAML is inappropriate, i.e., [they don't simply transfer across platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58009732/570918). Most of what is in this YAML is unnecessary (basically it only defines a Python env, with no substantial packages), so just make a new one from scratch that lists only the packages you need for your code to run.

Answer (score -1):

Try Adding this at the beginning of your DockerFile-

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
```

or changing the respective image name in docker-compose.yml

Comment: ya, added already, just now careless forgot to copy paste that part. Sorry for that. What do you mean by changing image name (i.e. node) in docker-compose.yml? Why the image name cause the error?